# Automatically change UID of file

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, groups, chown

Due to development policies, all my relevant server files have g+w policies. This is working great, but, for added accountability, I'd like the files to change owner UID upon being edited by other users with group permission. Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to consider source code management (svn or git).  It will not only tell you who edited what files but what exactly they changed in each file.  It will also allow you to undo any changes that turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: How the files are being accessed (via HTTP, SMB, SSH, ..)?

Comment: @ChrisNava I don't want to spend the HD space storing file history; I just want to know who last changed.

Comment: @Khaled SSH-based methods only (such as standard shell, scp or SFTP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inotify and incron.
Here there are some documentation: 
http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=common&page=home&lang=en
http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656876/determine-uid-that-last-modified-a-file-in-linux